# Approach to store large models for Country / County / State Drop downs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, localization

I'm developing an app in angular and there are a few forms dotted around different pages that have large drop downs for county, country, city etc. It makes sense to use either ng-repeat or ng-options and store the options in a model so instead of repeating myself I thought it would be a good idea to have a single location for the model.

I'm just researching different approaches to do so.

Currently I'm thinking of a factory like `$langAddress` with methods like `getCities('en')`, `getCounties('en')`, `getCountries('en')` etc.

And a model may look like this

```
var countries = {
    en: ['UK', 'SPAIN', 'JAPAN', 'BELGIUM'],
    es: ['UK', 'ESPAÑA', 'JAPÓN', 'BÉLGICA']
};

getCountries('es') //['UK', 'ESPAÑA', 'JAPÓN', 'BÉLGICA']
```

I could the use this array to populate my options in my dropdown.

Any ideas?

Thanks, James

Answer (score 0):

Yes, factories/services are the way to go. Keep the data/gets/sets in a factory/service away from your controller. Call them in your controller to bind to the view.